# move semantics and unique_ptr

Tags: c++, move-semantics, unique-ptr

How would you perform a move operation on a class that uses unique_ptr? Wouldn't setting the unique_ptr to null cause deletion of the data? If I perform a copy through a list initializer of the unique_ptr like so, would the data be preserved or deleted?

---

```
template<typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T>>
class forward_list
{
...
private:
    struct node
    {
        T data;
        std::unique_ptr<T> next;
    };
    std::unique_ptr<node> root_;
    std::unique_ptr<node> leaf_;
    size_t count_;
    const A& heap;
};
```

---

```
// Move constructor. Constructs the container with the contents of other using move semantics.
// If alloc is not provided, allocator is obtained by move-construction from the allocator belonging to other.
inline forward_list(forward_list&& other)
 : root_(other.root_), leaf_(other.leaf_), count_(other.count_), heap(other.heap)
{
    other.root_ = nullptr;
    other.leaf_ = nullptr;
    other.count_ = 0;
};
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to define a move constructor (unless `forward_list` has other special member functions defined that are not shown here). The compiler will generate a move constructor that'll do the right thing in this case (again, assuming there aren't other data members present that you haven't shown above).

Comment: I believe that unique_ptr already works similarly to move semantics in general. That means that at the point where your code assigns to the unique pointers, those are already null because their content was moved to the new pointers.

Comment: @Praetorian i have defined (not shown here for simplicity) many other member functions, including all of the ones defined for the stl forward_list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *move* the pointer.

```
forward_list(forward_list&& other) :
    root_(std::move(other.root_)),
    leaf_(std::move(other.leaf_)),
    count_(other.count_),
    heap(other.heap)
{
    // Do nothing
}
```